# Error on saving date format in file with pandas ExcelWriter

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to save an Excel file with date format and I got error.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date

df=dataframe with two columns: created_at (date format), name (number format)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('graph_data.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter',date_format='mm dd yyyy')

pd.DataFrame(df).to_excel(writer, 'Name') 

writer.save()
```

I obtain an Excel like following:

[image]

I can format the cells manually but I would like to format them directly in the code?

Comment: Try expanding your column in Excel to fit the data width ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html):

> If you require very controlled formatting of the dataframe output then you would probably be better off using Xlsxwriter directly with raw data taken from Pandas.

Then I suggest to do something like this:

```
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Name']
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 20)  # Assuming is the first column
writer.save()
```

Complete example [here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_datetime.html#ex-pandas-datetime)